# Check if password-protected web file exists

Tags: powershell, http, cmd

I need to check to see if a password-protected web file exists in a directory.

I keep getting a `(401) Unauthorized` error so, Lines 5-6 are not working.

**Script Code:**

```
$currdate = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
$Username = "username"
$Password = "password"
$url = "http://some.website/" + $currdate + "/somedirectory/some.file.txt"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
    Write-Host "File exists!" 
}
Else {
    Write-Host "File does not exist..."
}
$HTTP_Response.Close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A 404 means that the file does not exist, so it appears to be working properly.

Comment: It sounds like your `$url` isn't being formed properly, if the file exists when you manually check it, but isn't there when your code creates the URL.  Are you sure it would be **some.website20161024/somedirectory/some.file.txt**?  Seems like you're missing a `/`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that in the original post. Edited.

Comment: Still, if you go to **some.website/20161024/somedirectory/some.file.txt** you _do_ get data back?  As CodeCaster stated, a 404 means it worked, but didn't find the file.  Try doing a `Write-Host` right before you call the open URL, and check the formulated string to validate it.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually a 401 error.

Comment: It's going to be tough to validate your `Networkcredential` line, but that's likely related.  Depending on what you're validating, check the `$Username` and `$Password` as well.  Debug those, and ensure they're perfectly functional when manually attempted.

Comment: Can you try to access the $url from the browser using your credential?Are you connected.

Comment: Yes, the URL path is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two objects WebClient and WebRequest, you need only one.

You set the credential to WebClient, but you do response by WebRequest without credential.

Modify your code  as:

```
    $currdate = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
    $Username = "xxxxx"
    $Password = "xxxxxx"
    $url = "http://some.website/" + $currdate + "/somedirectory/some.file.txt"      

    # comment these lines,you use WebRequest
    #$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    #$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)

    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)

    #add this line
    $HTTP_Request.Credentials = new-object system.net.networkcredential($Username, $Password)

    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
        Write-Host "File exists!" 
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "File does not exist..."
    }
    $HTTP_Response.Close()
```